# printf printing more than one element of an array

Tags: c

If I type in "qwer" for example, this would give me back "er" for the output. How come "r" is also output if I'm only asking for userIn[2]?

Also, is there a less dirty alternative to "char userIn[256]"? The way I see it, the 256 limit predetermines what the user can type in, which is bad. But I don't know how to make it so that userIn doesn't have a predetermined size.

```
char userIn[256];
printf("Type the message to be encoded: ");
scanf("%s", &userIn);
printf("\n");;
printf("This was typed: %s\n", &userIn[2]);
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &userIn);` is not correct and gives a compile warning, your should read strings without `&` -> `scanf("%s", userIn);`. The format `%s` expects an argument of type `char*` and with `&userIn` you are passing `char (*)[256]`.

Answer (score 5):

You are not asking for `userIn[2]`. You are asking for a *string* that begins at `&userIn[2]`. Format specifier `%s` means "string". The string that begins at `&userIn[2]` is indeed `"er"`. Which is what you see as your output.

If you want to print a single character, you can use `%c` format specifier and pass in `userIn[2]` instead of `&userIn[2]`

```
printf("%c\n", userIn[2]);
```

Alternatively, you can use `%s`, but in this case you have to explicitly limit the length of the string to be printed through precision specifier, as in

```
printf("%.1s\n", &userIn[2]);
```

The above means: print the string, but don't output more than 1 character.

P.S. As it has been noted in the comments, your `scanf` call is incorrect. It should be either `scanf("%s", userIn)` or `scanf("%s", &userIn[0])`, but not what you have now. What you have now will typically "work", but the type of the pointer is still incorrect. Many compilers will issue a warning about this.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Can you explain how come when it was %s, I had to pass it a pointer but not when it was %c?

Comment: @user2797058: Well, because that's what the spec of `printf` wants you to pass. If you use `%s`, you have to pass a pointer to the beginning of the string. If you use `%c`, you have to pass the character value itself. There's no other "why" besides the fact that `printf` spec says so.

Answer (score 3):

You are telling printf to print a string and give it the address of the third character. If you do

```
printf("This was typed: %c\n", userIn[2]);
```

instead, it will only print 'e'.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are using "%s" instead of "%c".  %s signifies a null-terminated string where as %c is a single character.  Using %s in your case prints "er" because that is the rest of the string starting at the array position you specified, until the null-termination character is found.

Replace

```
printf("This was typed: %s\n", &userIn[2]);
```

with

```
printf("This was typed: %c\n", &userIn[2]);
```